# EF CAST on Select

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am currenty working on a Database that has a custom CLR type for one of its columns, if I try to use an EDMX file, it doesn't event recognize the column or allow me to include it in the list of properties for the table

I created a property on my model object(since I am using Dynamic DBConext in my code, so I only needed the EDMX to copy the class files generated), this works out ok and runs a Database query, when it does come back to converting the query, I get an error that shows that EF is looking for the custom CLR type DLL,

I would like to somehow create a CAST or Convert on the Query that is sent to SQL to convert it before it comes back to my application

The type is defined as follows(I tried to force it to be a specific type)

```
[Column(TypeName = "varbinary(max)")]

public byte[] WKBData { get; set; }
```

The OnModelCreating method

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new WKBModelMap(wkbTableName, schema));
```

The ModelMap

```
public WKBModelMap(string tableIdentifier, string schema = "mrc")
        {
            this.HasKey(t => t.ElementID);//set the primary key of the EAV table

            //map the tablename
            string tableName = $"{schema}.{tableIdentifier}";
            this.ToTable(tableName);
            //this.Property(p => p.WKBData);

        }
```

I use a generic Repository class to get my data

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query);
            }
            else
            {
                return query;
            }
        }
```

So when I call the Get method, I the CLR type exception pops up, So I wanted to know, can I use a cast on the above class/mapping to force EF to build a CAST or convert on the select?